# Esta edição está correta?

Tags: suporte, edição, edições-sugeridas

Estava navegando por perguntas antigas aqui, e me deparei com essa edição:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/227621

Pode-se perceber que a OP editou a resposta respondendo a própria pergunta, provavelmente por não saber bem como manusear no site.

Mas o que me assustou um pouco foi ver que o OP não tinha pontos pra editar diretamente, então a sugestão dela foi aprovada na fila.

Sei que a pergunta é antiga, mas é possível reverter? Não soube como sinalizar ela, nenhuma opção pareceu encaixar nessa ocasião.

Comment: Não tenho reputação pra reverter :(

Comment: O maior erro foi de quem aprovou. Estou revertendo, não irei suspender "da fila" os usuários que aprovaram, pois é uma situação bastante antiga. Obrigado por reportar.

Answer (score 4):

Estava errado e reverti, obrigado. A análise está correta. Você poderia só sinalizar um caso assim que não precisa de debate.

O debate, especialmente sobre a aprovação é bem-vindo, mas a esta altura, inócuo.